# Capture a variable in the closest outer scope

Tags: julia

In Julia, all variable assignments in a function are local by default, but you can use the `global` keyword to assign to a global variable instead. How to assign to a variable to an outer but non-global scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on what exactly you're trying to do. If there is a variable that already exists (assigned or declared) in an outer local scope and it isn't shadowed in an inner local scope then you can just assign to it. What you cannot do is assign a variable to an outer local scope that hasn't been declared from that scope. You also cannot assign to a local variable that has been shadowed by a different local in an inner local scope. I'll try to give examples of each of these.

To start with, here's a couple of things you can do with globals. First, you can create an entirely new global from a local scope with the `global` keyword:

```
julia> function g1()
           global X = "hi"
       end
g1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g1();

julia> X
"hi"
```

Next, you can also re-assign an already assigned global:

```
julia> function g2()
           global X = "bye"
       end
g2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> X
"hi"

julia> g2();

julia> X
"bye"
```

Now let's try something similar to the first thing where the outer scope is local:

```
julia> function outer1(call::Bool)
           # no declaration of x
           function inner1()
               x = "inner" # local to inner1
           end
           call && inner1()
           @isdefined x # false
       end
outer1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> outer1(false)
false

julia> outer1(true)
false
```

This does not work as `x` is local to `inner1` and is undefined in `outer1`. It doesn't matter whether `inner1` is called or not—`x` is never defined in `outer1`. Moreover, there is no keyword that can be used in `inner1` to make `x` appear in `outer1`.

What you can do, however, is assign to an outer local variable that has already been created in the outer scope:

```
julia> function outer2(call::Bool)
           x = "outer"
           function inner2()
               x = "inner" # same x as outer2
           end
           call && inner2()
           return x
       end
outer2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> outer2(false)
"outer"

julia> outer2(true)
"inner"
```

What if you don't want to give `x` an initial value in the outer scope? You can accomplish that by declaring it with `local` but not assigning any value:

```
julia> function outer3(call::Bool)
           local x # declare but don't assign
           function inner3()
               x = "inner" # same x as outer2
           end
           call && inner3()
           return @isdefined(x) ? x : nothing
       end
outer3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> outer3(false)

julia> outer3(true)
"inner"
```

Here if `inner3` is not called `x` remains undefined whereas if it is called, `x` has the value `"inner"`.

What if `x` is used as a new inner local that shadows an outer local by the same name? This can happen if the inner local is explicitly declared or is a function argument (arguments are always local to their function). Examples:

```
julia> function outer3(call::Bool)
           x = "outer"
           function inner3()
               local x = "inner" # new local in inner3
           end
           call && inner3()
           return x
       end
outer3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> outer3(false)
"outer"

julia> outer3(true)
"outer"
```

```
julia> function outer4(call::Bool)
           x = "outer"
           function inner4(x) # arg x is local to inner4
               x = "inner"
           end
           call && inner4(x)
           return x
       end
outer4 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> outer4(false)
"outer"

julia> outer4(true)
"outer"
```

In both of these cases assignment to the inner local has no effect on the outer binding.

Comment: The same reason you want to change global variables. However, I am going to use only pure functions anyway.

Comment: I'm doing a `WebSockets.open(url) do ws` block and I need to assign a response to a non-global but local variable. I think this is a pretty compelling use-case since the `do` block is inside a function.